# How to place captions of the side of a tikzpicture when it is inside a tcolorbox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, tcolorbox

I am using `tcolorbox`. In the `tcolorbox` there is a `tikzpicture`. Normally I caption the picture with `\captionof`. But, this time I want the caption to be on the side of the `tikzpicture`. How can i do this inside of the `tcolorbox`? Here is a working sample but with the captions at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myboxii}[1][]{
  breakable,
 freelance,
 title=#1,
 colback=white,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  bottomrule=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colframe=white,
  overlay unbroken and first={
  \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt]
    ([xshift=5pt]frame.north west) -- 
    (frame.north west) -- 
    (frame.south west);
  \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt]
    ([xshift=-5pt]frame.north east) -- 
    (frame.north east) -- 
    (frame.south east);
  },
  overlay unbroken app={
  \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt,line cap=rect]
    (frame.south west) -- 
    ([xshift=5pt]frame.south west);
  \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt,line cap=rect]
    (frame.south east) -- 
    ([xshift=-5pt]frame.south east);
  },
  overlay middle and last={
  \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt]
    (frame.north west) -- 
    (frame.south west);
  \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt]
    (frame.north east) -- 
    (frame.south east);
  },
  overlay last app={
  \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt,line cap=rect]
    (frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=5pt]frame.south west);
  \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt,line cap=rect]
   (frame.south east) --
    ([xshift=-5pt]frame.south east);
  },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myboxii}[Graph ]
        \captionsetup{type=figure} 
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [draw=black]  () at (0,0) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{test123}
        \label{fig:test}
    \end{myboxii}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I find this `tikzpicture` weird, but you can test `sidebyside` and placing the `tikzpicture` environment either in the upper or the lower box and the `\captionof` in the other part of the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use a `sidebyside` box approach, placing the caption on the left, meaning in the upper part and the image in the lower part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myboxii}[2][]{
  breakable,
  freelance,
  title=#2,
  colback=white,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  bottomrule=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colframe=white,
  overlay unbroken and first={
    \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt]
    ([xshift=5pt]frame.north west) -- 
    (frame.north west) -- 
    (frame.south west);
    \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt]
    ([xshift=-5pt]frame.north east) -- 
        (frame.north east) -- 
        (frame.south east);
      },
      overlay unbroken app={
        \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt,line cap=rect]
        (frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=5pt]frame.south west);
        \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt,line cap=rect]
        (frame.south east) -- 
        ([xshift=-5pt]frame.south east);
      },
      overlay middle and last={
        \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt]
        (frame.north west) -- 
        (frame.south west);
        \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt]
        (frame.north east) -- 
        (frame.south east);
      },
      overlay last app={
        \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt,line cap=rect]
        (frame.south west) --
        ([xshift=5pt]frame.south west);
        \draw[blue!75!black,line width=3pt,line cap=rect]
        (frame.south east) --
        ([xshift=-5pt]frame.south east);
      },
      #1
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{myboxii}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top seam]{Graph }
      \captionof{figure}{test123}%
      \label{fig:test}
      \tcblower
      \centering

      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw=black,fill=red]  () at (0,0) {};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{myboxii}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @arcGuesser: You're welcome. You can adjust the gap and righthand ration with the appropriate options, see the `Side by side` section in the `tcolorbox` manual